# Flink keyedstream generate duplicate results with same key and window timestamp

Tags: duplicates, apache-flink

Here is my Flink job workflow:

```java
DataStream<FlinkEvent> events = env.addSource( consumer ).flatMap(...).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks( new EventTsExtractor() );
DataStream<SessionStatEvent> sessionEvents = events.keyBy( 
    new KeySelector<FlinkEvent, Tuple2<String, String> >()
            {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> getKey( FlinkEvent value ) throws Exception {
                    return(Tuple2.of( value.getF0(), value.getSessionID ) );
                }
            } )
      .window( TumblingEventTimeWindows.of( Time.minutes( 2 ) ) )
      .allowedLateness( Time.seconds( 10 ) )
      .aggregate( new SessionStatAggregator(), new SessionStatProcessor() );
/* ... */
sessionEvents.addSink( esSinkBuilder.build() );
```

First I encountered

> java.lang.Exception: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator

in `flatMap` operator and the task keep restarting. I observed many duplicate results with different value by same key and window timestamp.

**Q1: I guess the duplicates was becaused the downstream operators consume message duplicately after job restarted. Am I right?**
I resubmitted the job after fixed the `ExceptionInChainedOperatorException` problem. I observed duplicates in the first time window again. And after that, the job seems to worked out right (one result in one time window per key).

**Q2: Where did the duplicates come from?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... there should be one result per key for one window

This is not (entirely) correct. Because of the allowedLateness, any late events (within the period of allowed lateness) will cause late (or in other words, extra) firings of the relevant windows. With the default EventTimeTrigger (which you appear to be using), each late event causes an additional window firing, and an updated window result will be emitted.

Answer (score 3):

This is how Flink achieves exactly-once semantics. In case of failures Flink replays events from the last successful checkpoint. It is important to note that exactly-once means affecting state once, not processing / publishing events exactly once.

Answering Q1: yes, each restart resulted in processing the same messages over and over again
Answering Q2: first window after your bug fix processed these messages again; then everything went back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm still confused about Q2. I mean even these messages been processed again, there should be one result per key for one window. I canceled and resubmitted the job at 17:52. Event time is the much the same as the enque time to kafka(several seconds diff at most). So the old job should had not generated results in following windows. Actually I observed duplicate results in 17:54 and 17:56 window (window end time). Maybe next time I should add insert time to the result to see more details.

Comment: This is only relevant if the job was restarted from a checkpoint or savepoint, but it doesn't sound like that was the case.